# Nested switch leads to an infinite loop

Tags: c, switch-statement, infinite-loop

In the following program, I need to change the initial and final characters to their respective characters as mentioned below in case but this is giving me an infinite loop. What should I do to fix it?

```
int main(void)
{
 char state ='t';
 char word[20]="aaabbccaaaaccbbb";

 int initiallength = strlen(word)-1; strcat(word,"a");
 while(strlen(word)-1 >initiallength)
 {
   switch(state)
   {
     case 't':
       switch(word[strlen(word)-1])
       {
         case 'a':
           word[strlen(word)-1]='b'; break;
         case 'b':
           word[strlen(word)-1]='c'; break;
         case 'c':
           word[strlen(word)-1]='d'; break;
         case 'd':
           word[strlen(word)-1]='\0'; break;
       }
       switch(word[0])
       {
         case 'a':
           word[0]='b'; break;
         case 'b':
           word[0]='c'; break;
         case 'c':
           word[0]='d'; break;
         case 'd': 
           word[0]='\0'; break;
       }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please format this code using the code block if you want any help.  It's impossible to read as it stands.

Comment: You mean that `abcde` will become `ebcda` ?

Comment: Run your program in a debugger and step through it line by line to see what its really doing.

Comment: Bar any other issues, you never update `initiallength`  or the length of `word`, , which means you need to think about what the while condition `strlen(word)-1 >initiallength` does.

Comment: @nos , The NUL-terminator in `word` is added in some positions. So `strlen(word)` would change

Comment: nor update `state` so the `switch(state)` is also useless

Comment: @CoolGuy The nul terminator is not added in any code paths that actually gets to run.

Comment: @Thomas in each iteration the program needs to switch into initial lettor and final lettor and it has to change the charactors i.e. if the initial word is 'a' it need to change 'a' to 'b' and this applies to both the sides.  But not 'abcde' as you wrote.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read your question & comment again like four times and I still don't understand what you want to do, maybe you could provide an example of what the code is supposed to do if Codejunky's answer doesn't fit your needs

Comment: This is working in infinite loop. bcz in 4rth loop `word[0]='\0'` , which make it empty string where as length will remain same. so will be run in infinite loop.

Comment: strlen becomes null and size_t is unsigned ==> infinite loop when first char of word is set to `\0`

Comment: @Himanshu yes that's what i thought. in case 'd' word[0]='\0' so is there is any way to eradicate this problem?

Comment: @user what is the exact output you required?

Comment: @himanshu in first iteration, the output needs to be  baabbccaaaaccbbc in second: caabbccaaaaccbbd.  in third: daabbccaaaaccbb (d is cleared in word[strlen(word)-1] ) and in the fourth iteration:  aabbccaaaaccbc  where 'd' from word[0] is cleared.

Comment: @user that conditions I have checked, I am asking what will be the correct output? is it same `aaabbccaaaaccbbb`.

Comment: @himanshu  when the loop is finished  then the word it generates is the output.

Comment: @user ,Use `while(((signed int)strlen(word))-1 >initiallength)`
or `while((signed int)(strlen(word)-1) >initiallength)` instead of `while(strlen(word)-1 >initiallength)` to fix the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do is swap the first and last characters in the given string. If that's the case first your code is way too complicated and second the reason you're getting an infinite loop is because the condition `strlen(word)-1 >initiallength` is always true.

Comment: could you mind explaning how strlen(word)-1 >initiallength is always true?

Comment: Listen when you initialized initiallength it was equal to the size of the string, and after that you added a character to the original string which makes its size know greater than initiallength. For your loop to come to an end you have to make the string smaller in each iteration untill its size is less than initiallength, otherwise strlen(words)-1 will be always greater than initiallength. If you explain to me what you want to do exactly I may be able to help you, I don't really see what are you trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

Test if word is empty

```
int main(void){                                                                
    char state ='t';                                                           
    char word[20]="aaabbccaaaaccbbb";                                          

    int initiallength = strlen(word)-1;                                        

    strcat(word,"a");                                                          

    while(strlen(word)-1 >initiallength && strlen(word) >= 0){                 
        printf("%d %d\n", strlen(word)-1, initiallength);                      
        printf("%d len %s\n", strlen(word), word);                             
        switch(state){                                                         
          case 't':                                                            
            switch(word[strlen(word)-1]){                                      
              case 'a':                                                        
              case 'b':                                                        
              case 'c':                                                        
                word[strlen(word)-1]++;                                        
                break;                                                         
              case 'd':                                                        
                word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';                                   
                break;                                                         
            }                                                                  

            switch(word[0]){                                                   
              case 'a':                                                        
              case 'b':                                                        
              case 'c':                                                        
                word[0]++;                                                     
                break;                                                         
              case 'd':                                                        
                word[0] = '\0';                                                
                break;                                                         
            }                                                                  
        }                                                                      
    }                                                                          
}
```

Comment: I think this will also run in infite loop.

Comment: So, the problem was with the comparison between -1 and 16( `strlen(word)-1 >initiallength`)?

Comment: @Himanshu yes it is running in infinite loop the problem is the -1 and 16 comparison. I don't understand the prog replace `>=` with `>` to stop infinite loop, but word will be set to an empty string